# Connect to same database from c# service and asp.net c# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This is not a duplicate question.  I search all of stackoverflow for the answer.  If it a duplicate, please point me to question that answers this.  The answers I found do not solve the issue.

I have developed a website with c# code behind with the connection string as follows:
       In the webconfig of the asp.net website and  and in the app.config of the 
      service:

```
 <connectionStrings>
     <add name="UsersConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=
 (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\[database].mdf;
   Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

In both c# code behind and service I have the following:

```
  SqlConnection connSN = new 
  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
 ["UsersConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

When I try to launch my service, I get the following:

> Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file 
>   mydatabase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified 
>   file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

How can I attach to the database with multiple services AND asp.net code behind?

Comment: Igor, the link you sent if for multiple database connections to different databases.  I am trying to use the same database with a connection between asp.net codebehind AND c# service app.

Comment: Just stop using attached databases and simple .mdf files for this. Setup a normal database on the server and specify its name in the configuration file, so no attach on connection is actually done. This is a bad practice Visual Studio tutorials frequently encourage.

Comment: Thank you Alejandro.  One question, I have always used attached...what would the connection string in the app.config look like?  I tried removing the attached database and of course it ran but it couldn't find the table.  Would it look like this:  <add name="UsersConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB\;Integrated Security=True"/>

Comment: Use something like: **Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB\;Initial Catalog=YourDbName;Integrated Security=True**. Also, have a look at the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) for all the valid connection string parameters.

Comment: Thank you Alejandro, it works great!